# Pivot a two-column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

**Question**

I have a dataframe `untidy`

```
  attribute value
0       age    49
1       sex     M
2    height   176
3       age    27
4       sex     F
5    height   172
```

where the values in the `'attribute'` column repeat periodically. The desired output is `tidy`

```
  age sex height
0  49   M    176
1  27   F    172
```

(The row and column order or additional labels don't matter, I can clean this up myself.)

Code for instantiation:

```
untidy = pd.DataFrame([['age', 49],['sex', 'M'],['height', 176],['age', 27],['sex', 'F'],['height', 172]], columns=['attribute', 'value'])
tidy = pd.DataFrame([[49, 'M', 176], [27, 'F', 172]], columns=['age', 'sex', 'height'])
```

---

**Attempts**

This looks like a simple pivot-operation, but my initial approach introduces `NaN` values:

```
>>> untidy.pivot(columns='attribute', values='value')                                                                                                       
attribute  age height  sex
0           49    NaN  NaN
1          NaN    NaN    M
2          NaN    176  NaN
3           27    NaN  NaN
4          NaN    NaN    F
5          NaN    172  NaN
```

Some messy attempts to fix this:

```
>>> untidy.pivot(columns='attribute', values='value').apply(lambda c: c.dropna().reset_index(drop=True))
attribute age height sex
0          49    176   M
1          27    172   F
```

```
>>> untidy.set_index([untidy.index//untidy['attribute'].nunique(), 'attribute']).unstack('attribute')
          value           
attribute   age height sex
0            49    176   M
1            27    172   F
```

What's the idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pandas.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html) with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for new index values and [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for remove columns name:

```
df = pd.pivot(index=untidy.groupby('attribute').cumcount(),
              columns=untidy['attribute'], 
              values=untidy['value']).rename_axis(None, axis=1) 
print (df)
  age height sex
0  49    176   M
1  27    172   F
```

Another solution:

```
df = (untidy.set_index([untidy.groupby('attribute').cumcount(), 'attribute'])['value']
            .unstack()
            .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to introduce a new column first with the cumulative count of age:

```
untidy["index"] = (untidy["attribute"] == "age").cumsum() - 1
```

Now untidy looks like

```
      attribute value  index
0       age    49      0
1       sex     M      0
2    height   176      0
3       age    27      1
4       sex     F      1
5    height   172      1
```

In this way you can create a multiindex dataframe based on attribute and index like this

```
tidy = untidy.set_index(["index", "attribute"]).unstack()
```

Which leads to the following format

```
              value           
attribute   age height sex
index                     
0            49    176   M
1            27    172   F
```

The only problem still left is that the columns is a multi-index now with a level too much. You can get rid of it but transposing the columns as index first, drop the level of the index and transposing it back

```
tidy = tidy.T.reset_index(level=0).drop("level_0", axis=1).T
```

The final result is your tidy data frame

```
    attribute age height sex
index                   
0          49    176   M
1          27    172   F
```

You can combine the second and third step to one of course. I am not sure if this is more idiomatic, but for me it is at least more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

[`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) should work fine, but if you are sure your labels repeat every 3rd row, you can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html) with a generator expression:

```
gen = (df.iloc[3*i:3*(i+1)].set_index('attribute').T for i in range(df.shape[0] // 3))
df = pd.concat(gen, ignore_index=True)

print(df)

attribute age sex height
0          49   M    176
1          27   F    172
```